# What is a single word for using something in a good way?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, antonyms

So, basically what I want is a word for using power in good way. Like opposite for 'abusing power'. Is there a word for that?

I wanted a good word for this sentence - 'The abuse or __ of power results in a collapsing or stable government, respectively'. I considered options like judicious. But nothing seems to properly convey the message. The concept of 'using something productively' seems very fundamental and I thought a fitting word for that would definitely be present.

Comment: Have you looked for antonyms of 'abuse' (not that I'm saying any would work here)?

Comment: Hi @EdwinAshworth, I tried looking for antonyms of 'abuse'. No luck. Nothing seems to fit.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. It's _evidence_ of reasonable research that's required on ELU (and really successful research would answer a question anyway).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: (1) I’m in favor of giving people the benefit of the doubt — so much so that I’ve been chastised for it — but even I don’t see any evidence of reasonable research (or reasonable evidence of research) here. Are you simply taking the OP at his word when he says “I tried looking … No luck.”? Have the standards here been lowered? — I didn’t see an announcement.  (2) If your ears are burning, it may be because [I mentioned you](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/407726/is-there-a-single-english-word-that-describes-the-inevitability-of-paternal-/409105#comment974960_409105).

Comment: @Scott I got the same results as OP when I looked for antonyms of 'abuse'. Have you any reasonable suggestions of what else to look up?

Comment: @Scott I got the same results as OP when I looked for antonyms of 'abuse'. Have you any reasonable suggestions of what else to look up? Sometimes, it's unreasonable to expect OP to provide much other than negative findings. You could ask him where he looked if you want to do due duty. I've done some work: your turn.

Comment: No, but I’m not really talking about the merits (or lack thereof) of this specific question. My point is that your turnabout of position, absent any substantial improvement in the question, is at variance with the standard procedures of users on this site (especially senior, high-rep users). Are we suddenly seeing a friendlier face of EL&U?

Comment: @RaghuramVadapalli: In case you haven’t found this, either: a value-neutral word for using power is *exercising*.   In the context of a democratic government, you could use *governing*; in the context of a monarchy, you could use *reigning* or *ruling*.   Perhaps you could use a word like these in conjunction with one (or more) of the adverbs that other people have been suggesting.

Comment: @Scott: Sorry for the late reply. I just got notified of this discussion. Thanks for the suggestions. Those don't really fit into what I was looking for. You can try putting those in the blank in this sentence - 'Abuse or __ of power results in a stable or collapsing government'. I considered options like judicious. But nothing seems to properly convey the message. The concept of 'using something productively' seems very fundamental and I thought a fitting word for that would definitely be present. I am updating the question with this information. I hope this qualifies as enough 'research'.

Answer (score 1):

The verb ***utilize***  according to [Oxford Living Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/utilize) means

> Make practical and effective use of

If we can take “*practical and effective* as equating to “in a good way,” this might be as close as you get.

Answer (score 0):

Would *benevolent* be what you're looking for?

Or more along the lines of *efficient* or *productive*?

Comment: If we can alter the form of the sentence, 'using power in a good way' will work. OP is asking for a (single word) antonym of _abuse_.

Comment: I think that *benevolent* (from the Latin *well-wishing*) would be OK if in context - a "benevolent god" or "benevolent ruler", for example. It doesn't inherently mean powerful, but has connotations of 'in a good way' and is frequently used to describe powerful individuals.

Comment: @K.Price:  You’re missing the point.  The question is (appears to be) asking for a verb, and you’re answering with adjectives.

Comment: Ah, apologies @Scott. I'll keep thinking.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do this with an adverb.  Helpful, beneficial, efficient, appropriate, etc., all having their subtle contextual differences.

But the literal antonym is "[disabuse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disabuse)."

I tried playing with the verb, "to use," and [other prefixes](http://www.prefixsuffix.com/rootchart.php), but nothing sounds right (in fact, most sound awful — "beneuse" or "benuse" ... ack!).

Comment: Disabuse doesn't mean what you say it means. My dictionary (NOAD?) has a clearer definition: *persuade (someone) that an idea or belief is mistaken*.